# Why do I have var/lib/docker~ directory and is it safe to remove?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

**Background**

I ran into the `no space left on device` error and upon running `df -i` I realized that I had almost 100% inode usage.

```
Filesystem                    Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                         1006563     470 1006093    1% /dev
tmpfs                        1015612     870 1014742    1% /run
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root 6496256 6309555  186701   98% /
```

Doing some digging with `for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done` on various directories I was able to narrow it down to `/var/lib/docker~/volumes` which had an absurd ~5.5 million size.

I have ran `docker system prune`, it doesn't affect the size of this directory.

**Questions**

1. Why do I even have this directory in the first place? I have the expected `var/lib/docker` directory which looks fine.
2. Is it safe to remove with `rm`?

Running Kubuntu 18.04 inside of a VMware Workstation 15 Player.

Comment: Is it a backup or failed backup? The tilde is suspect. How old are the files inside, do any have recent timestamps or are they all old?

Comment: @JohnKugelman perhaps, the folders inside seem to all be hashes, ie `ffcd50f1adc77b83aa1f4b19611fcb83ceb2bc4468b4f7f4dde27cded793990b`, inside those are folders such as `react` and `promise`. I don't know how old these files are.